# how to store answer into a database

Tags: laravel

I have created a multiple choice question and able to store them into a database, I need when a user select the correct answer it stores the id of the question and the answer. Please anyone who can help me how to do it

Here is my form for creating the questions

```
@foreach($qns as $qn)
   {{$qn->question_name}}
   <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="opt1">
         <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt1" 
           name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="a">{{$qn->opt1}}
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="opt2">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt2" 
            name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="b">{{$qn->opt2}}
       </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="opt3">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt3" 
             name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="c">{{$qn->opt3}}
        </label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="opt4">
             <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="opt4" 
             name="opt{{ $qn->id }}" value="d">{{$qn->opt4}}
         </label>
     </div>
 @endforeach
```

Here is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
   // dd($request->all());
   $this->validate($request,[
      'question_id' =>'required|string',
      'opt'.$qn->id  =>'required|string',   
   ]);

    $qn= Answer::create([
       'question_id'=>$request['question_id'],
       'opt'=>$request['opt'.$qn->id],

    ]);
}
```

Comment: can you share the full code of the form

Comment: I have showed you how to save answers in your previous question. Why don't you try that?

Comment: When i select the answer and submit ,the data is not inserted into a database but when a dd the request show me that data are posted

Comment: @zahidhasanemon i have tried your way to save but i get this error Call to a member function save() on null

Comment: Check out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like

```
public function saveAnswers(Request $request)
{
    $questions = Questions::all();
    foreach($questions as $qns){
        $name = "opt".$qns->id;
        Answer::create([
            'question_id'=>$qns->id,
            'answer'=>$request->$name,

        ]);
    }
}
```